# Object of type 'WinFormsBlazor.Pages.Home.BookComponents.AddImageOrAudio' does not have a property matching the name '‌BookID‌'

Tags: blazor

I use a radzen dialogservice to open a component with parameters and in the same project I did it many times.But this one is not working and says:

: Object of type 'WinFormsBlazor.Pages.Home.BookComponents.AddImageOrAudio' does not have a property matching the name '‌BookID‌'.

I open the component using this code:

```
 await dialogService.OpenAsync<BookComponents.AddImageOrAudio>("افزودن صدا",
           new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "‌BookID‌", selectedBook.Id }, { "PageID", selectedPageID }, { "FileType", BookFileType.Audio } },
           new DialogOptions() { Width = "500px", Height = "450px" });
```

when I debug, The selectedBook.Id and selectedPageID both have values.
The component I am trying to open is:

```
<h1>Hello Add @(FileType.ToString()))</h1>
   

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public int BookID { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int PageID { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public BookFileType FileType { get; set; }

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        }
}
```

and it is resided exactly in the stated path (in the error).

why this component does not open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite { "‌BookID‌", selectedBook.Id } manually and problem solved.